# Associated primes and torsion functors

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, let $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq R$ be an ideal, and let $M$ be an $R$-module.

We denote by $\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M)$ the $\mathfrak{a}$-torsion submodule of $M$, by ${\rm Var}(\mathfrak{a})$ the set of primes containing $\mathfrak{a}$, and by ${\rm Ass}_R(M)$ the set of associated primes of $M$.

We have the following relations between ${\rm Ass}_R(M)$, ${\rm Ass}_R(\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M))$ and ${\rm Ass}_R(M/\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M))$:

> $$\tag{1}{\rm Ass}_R(M)\cap{\rm Var}(\mathfrak{a})={\rm Ass}_R(\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M)).$$
>   $$\tag{2}{\rm Ass}_R(M)\setminus{\rm Var}(\mathfrak{a})\subseteq{\rm Ass}_R(M/\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M)).$$

The inclusion in (2) is an equality if $M$ is noetherian, but not in general.

A counterexample is obtained as follows: Let $K$ be a field, let $$R=K[(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}]/\langle\{X_iX_j\mid i,j\in\mathbb{N},i\neq j\}\cup\{X_i^{i+1}\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}\rangle,$$ denote by $Y_i$ the canonical image of $X_i$ in $R$, and let $\mathfrak{m}=\langle Y_i\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\rangle$. Then, $${\rm Ass}_R(R)\setminus{\rm Var}(\mathfrak{m})=\emptyset\subsetneqq\{\mathfrak{m}\}={\rm Ass}_R(R/\Gamma_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)).$$

Note that the supporting ideal in this example is not of finite type. Since torsion functors whose supporting ideals are of finite type are often better behaved than arbitrary ones, we may ask the following question:

> Is the inclusion in (2) an equality if $\mathfrak{a}$ is of finite type?

(EDIT: If we replace the set of associated primes by the set of *weakly associated primes* then we still have an inclusion $\supseteq$ in (1) and an inclusion $\subseteq$ in (2). The above counterexample also shows that the inclusion in (2) may be strict. I am also interested in the questions whether the weakly associated primes version of (1) is an equality, and whether the weakly associated primes version of (2) is an equality for $\mathfrak{a}$ of finite type.)

Comment: For non-Noetherian rings there are several different notions of "associated prime".  Weak Bourbaki associated primes, Krull primes, and strong Krull primes almost always work better in the non-Noetherian setting than (strict Bourbaki) "associated primes."

Comment: @Jesse: Yes, I know these, and I also have some related problems concerning their interplay with torsion functors. But here I am only interested in the (usual) associated primes. (But if you know how the relations (1) and (2) look like for any of these other notions I would be happy to see it.) Moreover, the _ring_ in my question may be noetherian.